# filter list of directories using ant

Tags: ant

I'm pretty new with ant, but I need to implement a filter for directories which starts fro example with 'example'. Lets suppose, that I have a folder

```
A:
-example.a
-example.b
-example.c
-test1
-test2
```

So, basically I want to get the list of folders, which starts with example.* and do some work with them...

I have this, but it does not work, the echo output is still empty

```
 <dirset id="aa" dir="../../../../A" includes="example.*"/>
 <property name="bb" refid="aa"/> 
 <echo>${bb}</echo>
```

Do you have any ideas, what I;m doing wrong?

Comment: Check that the directory ../../../../A relative to the basedir of the build actually exists.  For me, the above works fine.

Comment: ok I tried it on dir="c:\" includes="Program *" and the input was all the files in c, but not folders :(

Comment: I guess may be that is why the output was empty, since I do not have files inA folder...